# Notification sounds in Kiosk Mode

Tags: android, android-management-api

I am using the Android Management API for devices used in Care Homes. The requirement is that the devices are locked down to a standard that means users cannot mess about with the device, but gives them enough access to the apps they need to do their work.

The issue I face is that the users require the devices to have multiple applications on them - 2 to 3 apps - and one of those applications is an alert system that warns users that someone requires assistance in another room. This system triggers a notification alert on the device.

The issue i face is as follows;
- The device needs to be in Kiosk mode to restrict access to settings and the likes
- When the device is in kiosk mode, notification sounds are not played.
- How can I enable notification sounds using the Android Management API for applications that are accessible in kiosk mode and trigger notifications alerts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MediaPlayer as the notification sound, by starting a Service that play's the MediaPlayer when the notification is shown.

Comment: Where would I set this? I, unfortunately, have no control over the development of the other apps on the device to decide what/how they trigger their sounds. When I turn kiosk mode off, the sounds work just fine. With kiosk, and no other changes, they stop working

Comment: Yes for other apps you cannot do this solution. If you are developing your apps then you can.

Comment: Thanks! I've started work on a notification bridge instead to work around this. Hitting new problems now but unrelated to this post - I've started a new question